# Finding the probability of the disease

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, bayes-theorem

Only 0.01% of people have triskaidekaphobia. The Dreizehn Club has developed a test for the phobia. If you have Triskadekaphobia, the test is 99% likely to identify that you have the disease. Unfortunately, it is also 5% likely to claim you have the disease when you don’t. If you take the test twice and it twice claims you have the disease, what is the probability that you do have the disease?

I have tried solving the problem using Bayes' theorem however my calculated answer seems to be incorrect. The answer for the problem is 0.0377.

Here's what I tried so far:
Let P(D) be the probability of having the disease and P(T) be the probability of the test being positive.
P(T) = P(T|D)*P(D) + P(T|!D)*P(!D)

Pr(D|$T^2$)=$\frac{Pr(T^2|D)Pr(D)}{Pr(T^2)}$

Why does this not work?

Comment: Let $T$ be the event you have the disease, and let $P$ be the probability you test positive twice. We want $\Pr(T\mid P)$, which is $\frac{\Pr(T\cap P)}{\Pr(P)}$. Now you have to evaluate two probabilities.

Comment: For this type of question it is usually very helpful to draw a tree diagram.

Comment: It would help if you showed your calculation.  We can't see where you went wrong if we can't see where you went at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you might have miscomputed $Pr(T^2)$

Since we are computing probability (a ratio), we can as well use the $\%$ figures directly,
if you aren't getting it, try

> $\dfrac{0.01\times99^2}{0.01\times99^2 + 99.99\times5^2}$

Comment: For your denominator why do you not whole square the entire equation i.e. $P(T^2) = (P(T|D)*P(D) + P(T|!D)*P(!D))^2$

Comment: The 2 terms in the denominator of my answer successively represent *Pr* of diseased people testing positive twice and healthy people testing positive twice. Squaring the overall *Pr* of people testing positive *once* is not the same thing !

Answer (score 0):

$P(D)=0.0001$

$P(T_n\mid D) = .99, P(T_n\mid D')=0.05$

Find $P(D\mid T_1, T_2) = \dfrac{\overline{\underline{|\qquad\qquad|}}}{\overline{\underline{|\qquad\qquad|}}+\overline{\underline{|\qquad\qquad|}}} \approx 0.037{\small 7}$